# Varnish FetchError for up to 30s after reload

Tags: varnish

I have a varnish 6 setup with 26 backends and after ram upgrade I have a problem where it throws 503 error after reload for about 15-30s and varnishlog says its - FetchError     backend reload_20190417_131210_1488.server15: unhealthy

Full headers from varnishlog:

> - << BeReq    >> 106235039
> - Begin          bereq 106235038 fetch
> - Timestamp      Start: 1555506951.751066 0.000000 0.000000
> - BereqMethod    GET
> - BereqURL       /_files/b6/ee/59/4f/af/b6ee594fafd3f13556216d89452f3dd4_1.jpg
> - BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
> - BereqHeader    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103
>     Safari/537.36
> - BereqHeader    Accept: image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
> - BereqHeader    Referer: http://www.example.com/
> - BereqHeader    Accept-Language: lv
> - BereqHeader    x-range: bytes=1135466-1135466
> - BereqHeader    grace: none
> - BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 84.237.232.159
> - BereqHeader    host: www.example.com
> - BereqHeader    Surrogate-Capability: key=ESI/1.0
> - BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
> - BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 106235039
> - VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
> - VCL_return     fetch
> - FetchError     backend reload_20190417_131210_1488.server15: unhealthy
> - Timestamp      Beresp: 1555506951.751106 0.000040 0.000040
> - Timestamp      Error: 1555506951.751111 0.000045 0.000005
> - BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
> - BerespStatus   503
> - BerespReason   Service Unavailable
> - BerespReason   Backend fetch failed
> - BerespHeader   Date: Wed, 17 Apr 2019 13:15:51 GMT
> - BerespHeader   Server: Varnish
> - VCL_call       BACKEND_ERROR
> - BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
> - BerespHeader   Retry-After: 5
> - VCL_return     deliver
> - Storage        malloc Transient
> - Length         286
> - BereqAcct      0 0 0 0 0 0
> - End

We had 16 GB ram will malloc 8 GB and now it is 32 GB with 23 GB malloc. We are using varnish 6 with VSF so it is pretty complex setup but it worked just fine. It compiles just fine without any error but throws 503 backend fetch fail to some domains after reload.

Answer (score 0):

The FetchError  is pretty clear, the backend is sick. Check it using `varnishadm backend.health`, it should tell you what is failing.

Showing your backend definition would help too.

Comment: Its not sick and its not just one backend. It happens after reload to just few sites for up to 30s. Other sites from same backend loads just fine in the same time.

Comment: ooooooh, you may be hitting a bug in 6. do your probes have different intervals?

Comment: All of them have 5s interval. Few of them dont have it at all.

Comment: Is it a known issue in 6?

Comment: it is (https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/issues/2976), but I'm not sure it's the issue here. Do you have any `.initial` in your probe definitions? What does `varnishadm backend_health -p` look like when you have the issue?

Comment: I dont have any initial definitions.

Does 6.0 even have such a command?
varnishadm backend_health -p
Unknown request.
Type 'help' for more info.

Command failed with error code 101

Comment: Is it varnishadm backend.list now?

Comment: Just tested and it marked 4 backends as sick after reload. This is how one of them looks: 
reload_20190510_123030_24536.server6 probe      Sick                1/2 Fri, 10 May 2019 12:33:55 GMT

Comment: Checked again and this time it marked almost half as sick.